Azure - ignore a policy when a change comes from a specific user
I have a policy that denies changes on resources that have the tag source:terraform.
However I want that policy to only block changes from the UI and not from azure devops.
So I want to exclude the technical user that azure devops is using, from the policy, so that changes on terraform resources via UI are not possible, but via the azure devops pipeline.
Is it possible for an azure policy to add some users, that are excluded from that policy?

I want to exclude the technical user that azure devops is using, from the policy, so that changes on terraform resources via ui are not possible, but via the azure devops pipeline: I'd say that Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) is more suitable to do this, not Azure policies.

TL;DR Use Azure role-based access control (RBAC) instead of Azure policies to prevent specific users from modifying resources.
Azure policies vs Azure RBAC
Azure policies is not the ideal tool to prevent specific users from making changes to resources because it primarily focuses in implementing governance for resource consistency, regulatory compliance, security, cost, and management.
Specifically, some useful governance actions you can enforce with Azure Policy include:

Ensuring your team deploys Azure resources only to allowed regions
Enforcing the consistent application of tags
Requiring resources to send diagnostic logs to a Log Analytics workspace

Regarding security, Azure policies lacks the granularity to target individual users directly - instead, for user-specific access control, Azure RBAC should be used.
In short, Azure RBAC is an authorization system that helps you manage who has access to Azure resources, what they can do with those resources, and what areas they have access to.
Some common use cases of Azure RBAC include:

Allow one user to manage virtual machines in a subscription and another user to manage virtual networks
Allow a DBA group to manage SQL databases in a subscription
Allow a user to manage all resources in a resource group, such as virtual machines, websites, and subnets
Allow an application to access all resources in a resource group

Configure roles for each type of user
Concluding, instead of using Azure policies consider configuring different Azure RBAC roles/groups for each type of user - for example:

Administrators: Should have Owner or Contributor role. which allows full control over resources, including the ability to create, modify, and delete resources; and manage access control.
Automation identities/service principals: Should have Contributor role or sufficient permissions to perform automated tasks including the ability to create, modify, and delete resources. This role may have restricted permissions compared to administration users.
Read-only users: Should have Reader role or custom role with limited permissions suitable for viewing resources, retrieving information, and monitoring, without the ability to make changes.
Other users: For users who need to manage specific types of resources, you can create custom roles with the ability to manage specific kinds of resources such as databases, networking resources, and others. Consider creating groups such as Data administrator, Networking engineer, DevOps Engineer.

